# Преобразование цветной картинки в серую средствами CSS.

Tags: css

CSS:фильтр Gray он кросбраузерный... или как обычно? Если как обычно, то посоветуйте как можно сделать изображение в серых тонах по наведению мыши, но не спрайтами.

Answer (score 3):

Он как обычно. =)
Есть четыре способа:
Первые два предполагают такую конструкцию:

```
<div style="background-image: url()"><img src=""></div>
```

1) Спрайты(чем плохи? Серое изображение может генериться скриптом PHP)
2) Две отдельные картинки(аналогично. Серое может генериться PHP)

Еще два - такую: `<img src="" onmouseover="">`

Других кроссбраузерных вариантов, какбэ, нет.

P.S. Всякие сильверлайты, флэши и прочие - не рассматриваем

Answer (score 1):

Растянуть прозрачную картинку с class="gray", на фон задать цветную.

```
img.gray:hover{background-image:url('bgimage_gray.jpg');}
```

Вот только если картинки разные, им каждой придется подобную фигню задавать.
А решение на javascript вас не устроит?